# Force a specific date and time on a single Android app

Tags: android, adb

is it possible to force a specific date and time just for one Android app? And is it possible on a non-rooted device, maybe via adb? Thanks in advance.

The few suggestions I was able to find where limited to rooted devices. I'd like to force an app to view a different system date/time and to move forward in time with those settings

Comment: What do you mean from specific date and time? Can you explain more?

Comment: Technically possible is a lot but it will definitely not work using adb. App virtualization systems like "ParallelSpace" may be able to modify system calls to get time and date but I don't know that product in deep so I don't know if this is supported. Alternatively on a rooted phone with frida-server or an app with Frida-Gadget injected you could hook all date functions and modify them as you wish.

Comment: @Charman Hi, the plan is to set a different date and time for a single app , and make them go along with the original system date/time (and advance with their hours and days)